# Tensorflow list_physical_devices('GPU') returning empty list despite installing all required software

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, nvidia

I seem to be having an issue with the TensorFlow (version 2.13.0) python package. Tensorflow doesn't seem to be able to recognize my GPU (RTX 2070 Super) on Windows 11. I installed CUDA 12.2 as well as cuDNN 8.9.3, Visual Studio Code 2022, Copied my cuDNN libraries to the CUDA installation directory and added the directories to Path. However whenever I call `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` it returns an empty list without detecting my GPU which I'm sure supports CUDA 3. I'm not sure what my issue is but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the tensorflow version you are using ?

Comment: apologies for not stating, the version is 2.13.0

Comment: There is no more GPU support in native Windows Tensorflow  after version 2.10

Comment: oh, what's my best course of action? To downgrade tf or switch to a linux distro?

Comment: If you can go for a linux distro, that is the best solution as further updates for GPU support will be only for linux, OR downgrade to tensorflow<2.11

Comment: The options are discussed in the Tensorflow installation documentation — use WSL or  try the Direct-ML plugin for native CPU Tensorflow

Comment: Got WSL working, thank you :3